# CPU usage in iPad Simulator

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad

I am puzzled by a test involving iPad simulator. The only difference is the placement of `NSDateFormatter`.

#### First Scenario

`NSDateFormatter` initialization code placed in a dispatch queue. This means the initialization is performed every time the dispatch queue is called.

Output:

```
iPad Simulator CPU = 106% (constant)
```

#### Second Scenario

`NSDateFormatter` initialization code placed in a `viewDidLoad` method. This means the initialization is initialized once.

Output:

```
iPad Simulator CPU = 133% (fluctuates +/- 2%)
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't check performance in the simulator. Only test CPU usage on a device. The simulator is running on your computer's intel CPU. Always do performance tests on a real device. You might be looking at a bug or poor implementation in the simulator.

Comment: That is very true. The simulator runs against the OS X Cocoa frameworks instead of Cocoa touch. There are major differences in implementation lurking under the covers. Plus the memory and performance characteristics of the two systems are radically different.

Comment: Thanks guys! Appreciate your reply

Answer (score 1):

Memory allocation is the single most expensive non-disk operation. If you are running short blocks from a dispatch queue, each block is spending most if it's time allocating a date formatter.

By moving the date formatter initialization into viewDidLoad, you create one and only one date formatter and reuse it.

The lesson: Don't do memory allocations in oft-repeated code if you can help it.

Comment: Hey @Duncan C,  Thanks for getting back. I understand what you wrote but testing against the iPad simulator shows otherwise.